# Container View made in Storyboard will not change frame programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, containers

I have a container view, `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerView;`, but it won't move when I set its frame. Here is how I am trying:

```
- (void)setFramesForCategories
{
    CGRect frame = _containerView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 20;
    frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - 52;
    frame.size.width = 236;
    frame.size.height = 60 * [[_dataDict objectForKey:@"Key"] count];
    _containerView.frame = frame;
}
```

I know this is basic and it has worked for me before, when I was moving programmatically created objects, but it is not working for me now.

Comment: I have tried just using static numbers instead of algorithms, but that doesn't work either, if that is what you mean.

Comment: It probably has to do with the layout constraints put on the view in IB. You either need to change those, get rid of them, or change the container view's frame by changing the constraints, rather than explicitly setting the frame.

Comment: @rdelmar I did try removing the constraints before posting this question but the delete option was grayed out. How would I change them via code? Or, is there another way of removing them?

Comment: Thanks @rdelmar, you gave me enough info to figure out how to figure it out. I'll post the answer.

Comment: You can remove them with removeConstraint:, but you need to make outlets to the constraints to be able to pass them as arguments to that method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem I had was the constraints set up in Storyboard were overriding the frame change. This explains why I wasn't having the same issues with programmatically added objects. All I had to do to turn off constraints for the project was to go to the `Storyboard.storyboard` file, then make sure the "Utilities" sidebar is open and select the "File Inspector" tab. Then I scrolled down under "Interface Builder Document" and deselected "Use Autolayout." After this, I reran the the project to find setting the frame programmatically did work.

Comment: Why do you need to shut off autolayout?  Why not change the auto-layout constraints via code and then try your frame change above?

Comment: Autolayout, while in some cases offers a good solution to support multiple devices, is generally terrible for most projects. Don't feel bad to turn it off, it's not just you who's doing that.

Answer (score 3):

The "frame" property of a view is used for layout. If you have layout your container view in the storyboard and wanna move it in code. Try the "transform" property. Such as, "self.containerView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.containerView.transform, 0.0, 10.0);" => move up the container view for 10 points :)