# How to set frame of UIView in AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

First of all I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13748523/744616).

But somehow, we have requirement to change view programatically. And we have use Autolayout all over.

I have code something like this,

```
 self.containerView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,30,30);
```

This doesn't work. Though I can hide/show border. But I cannot change frame.

Please suggest any hack if not exact solution.

Comment: You don't set the frame in auto layout. the frame is calculated for you based on the constraints you give it.

Comment: You can update the constraints by removing the old one and adding new ones.

Comment: @CW0007007 I want to constantly change size of frame.

Comment: You would create instance variables for your constraints, which you can then change programatically as and when required.

Comment: have you spent any time learning even the most basic principles of Auto Layout? I would recommend it before asking the community to spend time helping you solve these problems.

Comment: I love what autolayout did for my frames but this ruined my app so bad that I just disabled autolayout.

Comment: @CW0007007 What if the view has no constraints?

Answer (score 2):

hope this will help

when auto layout is ON  you can't update the frame or bound of an ui element.

so you should set the auto layout OFF and then change the frame of your  element or if you already put lot of  constraints for managing your view and don't want to delete them , you should  update your constraint in such a way that constraint update your view.

second, if some object add programmatically in your view then your previously define constraint does not work on it .so for it you have to add constraint programmatically.

You can use the [Autolayout Constraints](http://autolayoutconstraints.com/) tool, to make this process easier.